# How to call terminal commands from eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a eclipse plugin to ease the development using a proprietary version control system.

Right now there is only a command prompt version of the system available for this VCS and its run in terminal. So from my eclipse plugin  I want to provide a simple menu options to do the things like check-out and check-in and internally call these commands.

My question is how can these terminal commands be called from eclipse plugin?

I am a newbie in eclipse plugin development.

Comment: This is no different from a normal Java program. Use Runtime.exec or ProcessBuilder

Answer (score 2):

Consider [ProcessBuilder class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) from java API to invoke external processes.

Also I recommend to consider [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) for this task. [It simplifies](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/faq.html) the external process invokation on multiplatform environment.

Comment: Thanks, but basically I want to run multiple commands sequentially( in the same prompt). Like 
command 1 : useview view_name
command 2 : create_activity activity_name
command 3: checkout file_path

How to do this?

Comment: Implement a separate Thread for every command and invoke it, either via ProcessBuilder class, or via Apache Commons Exec: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html